# Images damaged when upload from Java Servlet to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, xmlhttprequest-level2

I'm developing code for a Java Servlet to handle form image POST , and upload that image to Google Cloud Storage. I can upload images doing an ajax call POST, with XMLHttpRequest, and FormData. What i'm facing is that most times images stored are damaged, and can not be open.
Like this one(http://storage.googleapis.com/realtimevouchers/Porto_ribeira.jpg), but image is ok on my filesystem.
Could this be an error dealing with streams inside servlet code?

Here's the servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String ajaxUpdateResult = "";
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    String filePath = "";

    try {
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();

            String fileName = item.getName();
            System.out.println("Nome ficheiro->" + fileName);
            String mimeType = item.getContentType();
            System.out.println("mimeType->" + mimeType);
            InputStream content = item.openStream();

            // Process the input stream
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int len;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((len = content.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            int maxFileSize = 10 * (1024 * 1024); // 10 megs max
            if (baos.size() > maxFileSize) {
                throw new RuntimeException("File is > than " + maxFileSize);
            }

            FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            System.out.println("DEBUG:upload timeStamp->" + timeStamp);

            GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
                    .setBucket(BUCKETNAME).setKey(fileName)
                    .setMimeType(mimeType).setAcl("public_read")
                    .addUserMetadata("uploadTimeStamp", timeStamp.toString());
            AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService
                    .createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

            // Open a channel to write to it
            boolean lock = true;
            FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
                    writableFile, lock);
            // Different standard Java ways of writing to the channel
            // are possible.

            // This time we write to the channel directly
            writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));

            // Now finalize
            writeChannel.closeFinally();
            filePath = writableFile.getFullPath();

            // Do whatever with the content InputStream.
            // System.out.println(Streams.asString(content));//binary

            ajaxUpdateResult += "File " + fileName
                    + " is successfully uploaded\n\r";

        }

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Parsing file upload failed.", e);
    }
    org.json.JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("operationStatus", "SUCCESS");
        json.put("operationExecuted", "POST_TO_GCS");
        json.put("filePath", filePath);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("DEBUG:" + json.toString());
    log.info("LOGGER" + json.toString());
    response.getWriter().println(json.toString());
    response.getWriter().print(ajaxUpdateResult);
}
```

Comment: Image on local filesystem has 123 KB, and on Google Cloud Storage has only 8k.

Comment: Calling this way:
`code`writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray()));
Instead of:
`code`writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
uploads images with no problem!
Is this a solution?

Comment: yes, you are wrapping the wrong buffer.